# How to change background color in iOS/XCode on click

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to learn iOS programming. To start I want to change the background color of my view when a button is clicked. My entire code looks as follows, but when I click the button no change happens. I'm using Xcode 13.1. Also I'm using a storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSLog("The app has launched")

    }
    
    @IBAction func changeColorClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.myBtn.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
        NSLog("I want to change color to green")
    }
    
}
```

I see the NSLog message when I click, just no color change.

Comment: I'm able to change the color of the title text, just not the background of the button: `myBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)`

Answer (score 0):

Check a few things:

First make sure your IBOutlet and IBAction are connected to the button itself.

You don't need to declare self here as the button as its already declared above and you don't need to call an instance of the view controller you're using to access the button.

You can also declare it like this to change the colour of the button in the function:

```
myBtn.backgroundColor = .green
```

To change the button's background colour when pressed.

Update on this thread if you can get it working.